# In excel, which function is similar to INDIRECT?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large number of excel files that I need to use for getting data. 
I am looking for a function similar to INDIRECT, in order not to be necessary to have the files open to get the values. Can you help?

Thank you

Comment: Your only option if you don't want to have all your files open is: either you reference all the data from all spreadsheets with hyperlinks on your master spreadsheet, or you go the VBA way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using **ADO**..............here is a reference:

[Microsoft ADO Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)

Answer (score 0):

In your VBA, you need to first open the workbook:
Workbooks.Open()
Then you can use Workbooks("xxx").Worksheets("").Cells()  or Range() [depending on what you want to do].
When you are done taking out the info/data, then you close that worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `=INDIRECT()` or ADO or even VBA. Just reference the closed worksheet like this in a cell: `='S:\Temp\[T.xls]Sheet1'!$C$4`

It will update the values upon opening the workbook; you don't need to have the source workbook open at all. Or you can update them manually by choosing Edit Links from the Data tab in Excel.